# Laravel only retrieve Model Records if they belong to authenticated user

Tags: laravel, authentication, model, laravel-middleware

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and have a Model called `Order`.
To test things I've created two users and two Orders, each user having one Order.

I've just seen that I'm able to retrieve the order of someone who is not my current user. I'm retrieving a list of user's own orders using `Auth::user()->orders`. But in order to show the details of a specific order I do this:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $order = CustomerOrder::findOrFail($id)->with('products')->get();
    return view('order.show')
        ->with('order', $order);
}
```

What am I missing out here? Is there a middleware or something to tell the application to only allow access to orders associated with the authenticated user?

Edit: So I've tried to do it using a Policy `OrderPolicy` (CRUD).

The `view()` fucntion of the Policy:

```
/**
 * Determine whether the user can view the customerOrder.
 *
 * @param  \App\User  $user
 * @param  \App\CustomerOrder  $customerOrder
 * @return mixed
 */
public function view(User $user, CustomerOrder $customerOrder)
{
    return $user->id === $customerOrder->user_id;
}
```

And I've registered it in the `AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    Adress::class => AdressPolicy::class, //Doesn't work either
    Order::class => OrderPolicy::class
];
```

I can still check the Order for another user.

Comment: Out of interest, why would you downvote a normal question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options. The best option in my option is the use Policies. The documentation for this can be found here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Alternatively do could do something like:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $user = request()->user();

    $order = $user->orders()->with('products')->find($id)->get();

    return view('order.show', compact('order'));
}
```

With an orders relationship function on your user model.

---

## Updated Reply

With the policy you gave, and with your resource route, you should be able to do:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(CustomerOrder $order)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $order);

    return view('order.show', compact('order'));
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I gave Policies a go. I now have a OrderPolicy, registered it in the AuthServiceProvider and did: `public function view(User $user, CustomerOrder $customerOrder)
    {
        return $user->id === $customerOrder->user_id;
    }` but still it does not work, I can still check other Orders. Did I do somethign wrong?

Comment: @Scarwolf Update your question with new code please.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Please elaborate on why?

Comment: @Jono20201 Done

Comment: @Scarwolf Can you share your route too?

Comment: It's from a CRUD Controller `Route::resource('order', 'OrderController');`

Comment: @Scarwolf Try my updated answer. Using policies and implicit binding you should be able to achieve a really clean solution for this.

Comment: @Jono20201 Thanks. But this gives me "This action is unauthorized." though my user id is 1 and the "user_id" relation in the order-table is 1 also. Something wrong with the policy maybe?

Comment: Alright, got it working. Forget to Import my Model into the AuthServiceProvider

Comment: @Scarwolf Glad to hear you got it working. Its amazing how much of the leg work Laravel does for you sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use the defined relationship and tell it to only retrieve the one with id `$id`. Like this:

```
$customerOrder = auth()->user()->orders()->with('products')->find($id);
```

Comment: @Scarwolf if your goal is to get the order by ID, but only if it belongs to the user, use the code from this answer.

Comment: @devk you've forgot to add `with('products')` part.

Comment: @Jono20201 It does. It scopes the query to the results that belong to authenticated user. It uses relationship on user model to do that. At Alexey: That's true

Comment: @devk perfect. +1

Comment: This will work also but I feel like if Laravel's developers added Policies in order to this I will go that way. Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: @devk Sorry, wasn't commenting on your answer, I was replying to a comment by Alexey which was later removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get orders which belong to authenticated user, do this:

```
CustomerOrder::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->with('products')->find($id);
```

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin There you go to equal it out. The code does what author asked for (I think). I think the author only wants to get the order with `id` `$id`, not all users order. But he didn't make that clear (`->findOrFail($id)->get()` -  I'm not sure why the `->get()` at the end.

Comment: @dev thanks, I've realized what OP wants. Fixed my code too.

Comment: Should be noted this answer is less than ideal as it requires the developer to remember to search by user_id. A relationship forces searches on orders belonging to the given user and eliminates the risk of forgetting to add the where.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, 
first you create policy. 
second you register it. 
third you use something like `$this->authorize('view', $order);` in your normal controller. 
You are missing the third step, you can find the doc here:
[https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies][1]